# Using adafruit Flora or Adafruit Trinket + MPU-6050 3-Axis Gyroscope + nRF24L01+ together

Tags: arduino, wifi, accelerometer

I am trying to do a project where I need to transmit data from an object if the object is moved in a particular way. The restriction is that the device has to be as thin and small as possible. I am trying to figure out if I can integrate the following three modules:

1. An Adafruit trinket or Adafruit Flora controller
2. A MPU-6050 3-Axis Gyroscope (http://www.gearbest.com/development-boards/pp_22492.html?currency=USD&gclid=CMbguuOG9sICFYXtMgodDxoAfA)
3. A nRF24L01+ wifi module (https://www.nordicsemi.com/eng/Products/2.4GHz-RF/nRF24L01P)
4. Use a coin battery.

Does anyone have an idea if the above 3 things are integrable? Do I have any way to check that? Any idea will be appreciated.

Regards,
Zafar

Comment: Simple answer: Yes, but probably not with a coin cell. You may need a more powerful battery to drive the whole lot. Coin cells don't give much current.

Comment: If you really want something "as small and thin as possible" (and want to run it off a coin cell) then you will need to design your own board with just your required components.  Also, the nRF24L01 is _in no way_ wifi. It could do Zigbee.

Comment: Thanks for the input. For nRF24L01+, it is a wireless data transceiver. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

Using less components fulfills the requirement of "as small as possible".
So usage nRF24LE1 module + accelerometer input + coin battery (CR2032) can be simplest and power-saving solution.
There are nRF24LE1 modules with size of 15x15mm only.

Important thing, running device from coin battery implies wise power management: going to standby and awaking from interrupt. This is possible with nRF24LE1.

nRF24 itself is not Wi-Fi. It's special RF implementation, considered as low-power.
Wi-Fi module is not low-powered and likely won't work with coin battery.

Answer (score 1):

The Avoccado controller seems to be what you are looking for depending on your target size, quoting from http://avoccado.cc:

> Avoccado° is an open technology that can be embedded in everyday objects, transforming them into haptic, wireless input devices. Avoccado° is both the circuit board and the software that powers it.
>
> - Nordic Semiconductor nRF24L01+ wireless radio
> - InvenSense MPU-6050 gyroscope and accelerometer
> - Atmel ATmega328P micro controller